# What is an intuitive meaning of $E(\overline { X } )$ and $Var(\overline { X } )$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable distributed over, for example say, the Binomial Distribution. Then $P(X)$ is the probability of getting $x$ successful trials in $n$ total trials.

So I saw a notation that represents the mean of random variables that made me I feel sceptical about my understanding of all the notations I have known. So here's my understanding of the notations:

> When it says the expectation of $X$, $E(X)$, does it mean over a long
>   run, $E(X)$ is the likely number of successful trials? In other words,
>   the expected value of $X$ is the expected number of successful trials
>   we would expect in a long run?
>
> When it says the variance of $X$, $Var(X)$, does it mean how spread
>   out the probability of successful trials are? Like how far apart the
>   probability between the successful trials are?

Now, here's the confusing part. I see a notation like this: $\overline { X } =\frac { 1 }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ { X }_{ i } }  $ and this is called the mean of all the random variables. But it doesn't seem to make sense to me. $X$ is the random variable and carries the value that is the number of successful trials. The average of $X$ is like the average number of successful trials?

Does it then mean $\overline { X } =E(X)$?

Then, there is also the expectation of the mean of all the random variables, $E(\overline { X } )$. So does this represent the average of the average of all the random variables, which means $E(\overline { X } )=E(E(X))$? But at this point, I couldn't understand what it means intuitively. What does it mean here to say the *average of the average* of all random variables?

Similarly, $Var(\overline { X } )$ is also a confusing term to me. Since $\overline { X } $ is just the average value, what spread does it have?

What is the intuitive meaning of this $\overline { X } $ mean of all random variables $X$ and what does this add on to the meaning of $E(\overline { X } )$ and $Var(\overline { X } )$?

Comment: $\bar{X}$ is the average of a set of random variables, so is a variable itself (i.e. it depends on the particular values of the $X_i$ for any trial). Things like $E(X_i)$ are independent of any particular value for the $X_i$ but depend instead on the probability distribution for $X_i$.

Comment: Just adding to @AlexBecker's comment: In the discrete case, $E(X)$ is the mean over the whole sample space. It is *a priori*, and depends on an assumed probability distribution for the $X_i$. A given mean $\overline{X}$, however, is *a posteriori*, depending on a sample of values $X_1,\dots,X_n$.

Comment: You should have written $P(X=x)$ is the probability of getting $x$ successes in $n$ trials.  "$P(X)$" doesn't even mention $x$.

Comment: To rephrase the previous comments a bit, $E(X)$ is the average *with respect to the probability measure*, and $\text{Var}(X)$ is the average square of deviation from $E(X)$ *with respect to the probability measure*. Probability measure is something that in a sense tells you how to take meaningful averages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a vast population of people who have different heights, and you choose one at random.  That person's height is $X$.  $E(X)$ is the average height of everyone in the population.  Then you pick $20$ people at random.  Their heights are $X_1,\ldots,X_{20}$.  Their average height is $\bar{X} = (X_1+\cdots+X_{20})/20$.  That is a random variable because if you pick another set of $20$, it has a different value---thus it varies randomly.  The expected value $E(\bar{X})$ is the same as the expected value $E(X)$.  But the variance $\operatorname{var}(\bar{X})$ is smaller than the variance $\operatorname{var}(X)$, because on average one sample of $20$ differs less from another sample of $20$ than one individual differs from another individual.

Comment: Can I say that $X_1, \cdots ,X_20$ are actually numbers on its own. It is a random variable only because these group of people were *randomly* sampled. But this wouldn't this also mean that $X_1, \cdots ,X_20$ are actually the $\omega$ inside the population of $\Omega$? Also, since $E(\bar{X})=\bar{X} = (X_1+\cdots+X_{20})/20$ are sampled values, how would the $E(\bar{X})$ same as $E(X)$, which consists of the whole population's height which may make the mean value very different from the sampled people's height?

Comment: I didn't say $\bar{X}$ is the same as $E(X)$.  That would be false.  I said $E(\bar{X})$ is the same as $E(X)$.  Think about the difference.

Comment: You wrote "since $E(\bar{X}) = \bar{X}$.  That's not true at all.

Comment: Just to be explicit: $\bar{X}$ is based on only $20$ values, but $E(\bar{X})$ is based on all possible samples of $20$ from the whole population.

Answer (score 3):

You should think of $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ (when they exist) as *parameters* which describe the distribution of the random variable $X$.  They are numbers.  They are not random variables.  So, although you can write $E(E(X))$, it's not very useful since the expected value of a constant is just the constant.  So you have $E(E(X)) = E(X)$.

Sometimes it is helpful to call $E(X)$ the "population average."

Now, you should think of $\bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ as simply a function of $n$ random variables, albeit a very useful one.  You shouldn't equate it in your mind with the population average $E(X)$ (a number).  Rather $\bar{X}_n$ is a random variable.

Given some outcome $\omega$, you observe the sample values $x_1 = X_1(\omega), \dots, x_n = X_n(\omega)$ and you can compute the so called "sample average," which is a particular realization of $\bar{X}_n$, namely

$$\bar{X}_n(\omega) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

Now, this sample average is a number, but it could be quite different from the population average, the number $E(X)$.
However, the Law of Large Numbers says that if $n$ is large enough then (any realization of) $\bar{X}_n$ will be close to $E(X)$.

And, yes, you can take the expected value of the random variable $\bar{X}_n$, as you suggest, and you will simply have

$$E(\bar{X}_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i) = E(X)$$

(The last equality assumes the $X_i$ all come from a distribution with mean $E(X)$.)

As for the variance, no, $Var(X)$ does not measure the spread between successes in repeated trials.  Rather, it is a measure of the spread of the possible values of the function $X$ about its mean $E(X)$.  If the variance is larger (smaller) that means there is a larger (smaller) chance $X$ will take on a value far from $E(X)$.  In your example, the possible values are 0 and 1, with probabilities $(1-p)$ and $p$, say.  The variance would be much bigger if you chose, say, 0 and 100 as the possible values for $X$.

Finally, note that the variance of $\bar{X}_n$ gets smaller as $n$ gets larger.  This is telling you that the larger $n$ is, the more likely the observed value of $\bar{X}_n$ will be close to $E(X)$.

Comment: Small nitpick: for the SLLN the $n$ we need to take depends on $\omega$ whereas when you say "if $n$ is large enough then (for any realization of)..." it makes it sound as if we can choose $n$ which works uniformly for all $\omega$. It also doesn't hit the fact that it _doesn't_ work for all $\omega$, but almost all $\omega$ but I'm not sure how to say this at the appropriate level for OP.

Comment: I think you're using the word "parameter" too loosely.  When you have a parametrized family of probability distributions, you have parameters.  But $E(X)$ can exist regardless of anything about parametrized families.  You don't have to think about more than one distribution---let alone a parametrized family of distributions---to speak of $E(X)$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I disagree.  Even if we're speaking of a single distribution, if $E(X)$ exists, I see no problem with calling it a parameter of the distribution of $X$.  I suppose the term could be defined very narrowly, reserved for only those parameters which uniquely identify a distribution within a parametrized family, but that is too narrow, imho.  I prefer to take parameter to mean "feature of a distribution."  (For example, I would say the moments of a chi-square are parameters of the distribution, even though they are not *the* parameter we use to identify the distribution.)

Answer (score 0):

The distinction among $\bar X$, $E(\bar X)$ and $E(X)$ is indeed not obvious and in my personal oppinion, often not well clarified in introductory statistics courses. The same is valid for $V(X)$ and $S^2$ (variance from a sample).

Let's use your suggestion and consider a $X$ r.v. Binomial(n,p). For any discrete r.v. $X$, if $E(X)$ and $V(X)$ exist, $$E(X)=\sum_{x\in \Omega_x} x P(X=x)\ \text{and}\ \ V(X)=E[(X-E(X))^2]$$
in which $\Omega_x$ is the set of possible values for $X$. You can understand $E(X)$ and $V(X)$ as theoretical constants associated with the PMF. For the Binomial$(n,p)$, $E(X)=n p$ and $V(X)=np(1-p)$, constants that depend on the parameters $n$ and $p$ from the Binomial. You can regard them as the theoretical mean and theoretical variance associated with the Binomial(n,p).

Now consider an independent sample size $m$ from this variable $X$ Binomial$(n,p)$ given by $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_m$ and compute the average and the sample variance using:
$$\bar X_m=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i}{m}\ \ \text{and}\ \ S^2=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1} (X_i-\bar X_m)^2}{m-1}$$

Because of an important property of the operator $E(\cdot)$ it is true for any r.v.s $X$ and $Y$ and constants $a$ and $b$ that $$E(aX+bY)=aE(X)+bE(Y)$$.

Using this property we can compute $E(\bar X_m)$:
$$E(\bar X_m)=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{m} E(X_i)}{m}=\dfrac{m E(X)}{m}=E(X),$$
as for any $X_i$ from the sample, $E(X_i)=E(X)$. With some additional effort we can also show that $E(S^2)=V(X).$

This is the reason why $E(\bar X_m)=E(X)$. And by the Law of Large Numbers (LLN) it is true that (under regularity conditions) $\bar X_m$ converges to $E(X)$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$ by statistical notions. By the same reason $S^2$ converges to $V(X)$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$.

Let's return to our Binomial$(n,p)$ with $E(X)=n p$ and $V(X)=np(1-p)$ and do some experimentation. If, for instance, $n=10$ and $p=0.3$, we have $E(X)=10\times 0.3=3$ and $V(X)=10\times 0.3\times 0.7=2.1$

Using a statistical software, let us obtain 2 samples size m=5 from this Binomial$(n=10,p=0.3)$ (using for instance rbinom$(5,10,0.3)$ in software R):

1. Sample 1: 1,2,2,7,4  with $\bar X_5=3.2$ and $S^2=5.7$
2. Sample 2: 4,4,1,1,1  with $\bar X_5=2.2$ and $S^2=2.7$

Notice that, in both samples, $\bar X_5$ and $S^2$ are not equal $E(X)=3$ and $V(X)=2.1$. The values will tend to be closer as the sample size increases, as theoreticaly expected by the LLN.